# SetupClass cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, slick2d

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new SetupClass("Setup Test"));
    app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
    app.start();

 }
```

And I get this error: SetupClass cannot be resolved to a type

How to fix this ?

Comment: Well where do you *expect* `SetupClass` to come from?

Comment: Does this work? `AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new BasicGame("Setup Test"))`

Comment: `Cannot instantiate the type BasicGame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Slick2D myself. I come from SFML and Allegro with C++.
I must have been looking at the same tutorial you were, because the `new SetupClass("Setup Test"));` part came from a YouTube video tutorial for new Slick2D users.

Instead of SetupClass, you want to use the name of your class. In that YouTube tutorial, the instructor's class name for the game is SetupClass.